# Ordering of elements drawn from uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**Setting**

$$X_1,\ldots,X_n \overset{iid}{\sim} \mathcal{U}[0,1]$$

Next order them so that $x_{(1)} \le x_{(2)} \ldots\le x_{(n)}$

Find $F_{(k)}(t) = \Pr[X_{(k)} \le t]$ in terms of a binomial sum, and the density of $X_{(k)}$.

**Solution**

One possible expression is

$$\Pr[X_{(k)} \le t] = \sum_{j=k}^n \binom{n}{j} t^j (1-t)^{n-j}.$$ $(0 \le t \le 1)$

Please explain why this makes sense.

Next I should show the density may be expressed as

$$f_{(k)}(t) = n \binom{n-1}{k-1} t^{k-1} (1-t)^{n-k}.$$

This one I am very lost on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression for the probability is gotten in this way:

What is the probability that some **specific** $j$ elements are all less than or equal to $t$, but that the rest are greater than $t$?  That is obviously
$$t^j(1-t)^{n-j}$$

Now how many ways can I choose a that specific set of $j$ elements? That answer is $\binom{n}{j}$.  So the probaility that **exactly** $j$ elements are less than $t$ is
$$\binom{n}{j}t^j(1-t)^{n-j}$$

Now $F_{(k)}(t)$ is the probability that  **at least** $k$ elements are $\leq t$. So we have to add the probabilities for each individual $j \geq k$; that gives the sum for $j = k$ to $j=n$.